# typescript doesn't render dynamic url on reac-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

i have component YachtDetails:

```
import React from "react";
import {RouteComponentProps} from "react-router-dom";

interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<{id:string}> {}

const YachtDetails:React.FC<Props> = ({match}) => {
    return ()
```

and i get Error on my App.tsx in YachtingDetails:

```
function App() {
    const [show, toggle] = useToggler();


    return (

        <div style={{height: '100%', backgroundColor:'#fff5f5'}}>
            <Toolbar toggle={toggle}/>
            <Drawer show={show} toggle={toggle}/>
            <Backdrop/>
            <main style={{marginTop: '56px'}}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/yachts-for-rent/:id">
                        <YachtDetails/> *iget error Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': history, location, match
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </main>
            <Footer/>
        </div>

    );
}

export default App;
```

i am beginner and trying to make a dynamic url and fetch info from json file.

Comment: it means you are required to pass some props properties.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using typescript, you are telling the program that the component `YachtDetails` *must* have some properties, or else throw error.

These properties are these

```
interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<{id:string}> {}
```

so in order for your code to compile, it should be:

```
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();
  const match = useRouteMatch();

<YachtDetails history={history} location={location} match={match}/>
```

if you only need the `match` property, then you don't necessarily need to extend `RouteComponentProps`, you could do sth like this:

```
interface Props {
  match: any
}
```

Comment: after `const [show, toggle] = useToggler();` and before `return`

Comment: i get error on ```<YachtDetails history={history} location={location} match={match}/> ```Type 'match<{}>' is not assignable to type 'match<{ id: string; }>'.
  Property 'id' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ id: string; }'.